# Using Sizeof and malloc function in C

Tags: c, malloc, sizeof

I am a newbie to C,

My Problem is the following code,

```
int Max[10],*New_Max;
int length=5;
New_Max=(int)malloc(sizeof(int)*length));
printf("sizeof(Max)=%d,sizeof(New_Max)=%d",sizeof(Max),sizeof(New_Max));`
```

Output:

```
sizeof(Max)=40,sizeof(New_Max)=4
```

I Expect `sizeof(New_Max)` to be `20`, but it prints as `4`.

Can anyone explain the reason for it.

Comment: `New_Max` is a pointer. `4` is the size of a pointer on your computer.

Comment: because it's a pointer

Comment: Can you explain why would you expect it to be 20?

Comment: Why do you cast the return of `malloc` to `int`?

Comment: Standard warning (as Jens' question implies): Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends. Actually do not cast `void *` at all to other pointers. C is not C++.

Comment: Arrays are not pointer and pointers are no arrays.

Answer (score 2):

The following line allocates memory to what New_Max is pointing.

```
New_Max=(int)malloc(sizeof(int)*length));
```

And, the following line grabs the info about what a pointer size is :

```
sizeof(New_Max)
```

So, the size of what pointer is pointing and its own size are two different things. That's why you are getting size of New_Max to be 4.

Answer (score 1):

You are making wrong assumption, that `sizeof` behaves in the same way for both types of memory allocation. There is fundamental difference between *array* and *pointer* and how it relates to `sizeof`. If you provide it with array, like here:

```
int Max[10];
size_t size = sizeof(Max);
```

then you will get overall size, that is number of elements multiplied by size of each element, that is:

```
10 * sizeof(Max[0])
```

On the other hand, for pointers, it results into size of pointer itself, not taking any elements into account, thus what you get is just `sizeof(int *)`. It does not matter if it points to `NULL` or some array object, the size would be the same.

Note that, the proper format specifier for `sizeof` is `%zu`, not the `%d`.